# Trouble with long type in c++ on macOS

Tags: c++, macos

I am having troubles with `long` type on macOS ( Apple clang version 13.1.6, arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0 ) with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

void call_int64( std::int64_t& v )
{
   std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl;
}

void call_int32( std::int32_t& v )
{
   std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl;
}

void call_int16( std::int16_t& v )
{
   std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   long a = 0;
   call_int16( a );
   call_int32( a );
   call_int64( a );
   return 0;
}
```

which results in:

```
test-long-2.cpp:22:4: error: no matching function for call to 'call_int16'
   call_int16( a );
   ^~~~~~~~~~
test-long-2.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'std::int16_t &' (aka 'short &') for 1st argument
void call_int16( std::int16_t& v )
     ^
test-long-2.cpp:23:4: error: no matching function for call to 'call_int32'
   call_int32( a );
   ^~~~~~~~~~
test-long-2.cpp:9:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'std::int32_t &' (aka 'int &') for 1st argument
void call_int32( std::int32_t& v )
     ^
test-long-2.cpp:24:4: error: no matching function for call to 'call_int64'
   call_int64( a );
   ^~~~~~~~~~
test-long-2.cpp:4:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'std::int64_t &' (aka 'long long &') for 1st argument
void call_int64( std::int64_t& v )
     ^
3 errors generated.
```

So it seems that `long` cannot be converted to any std integral type. On linux, I am getting only two errors, long is accepted by `call_int64`.

Comment: There's no problem converting `long` to any other integral type. But that's not what the code is trying to do, and that's not what the compiler is complaining about. The code attempts to convert a `long&` (i.e., **reference** to `long`) into an `int16_t&` (i.e., **reference** to `int16_t`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that `long` is aliased to any of the `std::intX_t` type aliases. Relying on that is wrong. The concrete choices for the aliases `std::intX_t` are implementation-defined and can vary between compilers, platform, standard library implementation, etc.

On many platforms `long` and `long long` are both 64bit types and `in64_t` will alias only one of them. The other one will not have any `intX_t` alias in that case.

The types `long` and `long long` are different types even if they have the same size, alignment and representation and therefore an object of one of these types cannot bind a reference of the other type.

Because the references you are using are non-`const` lvalue references *conversions* from one of these types to the other are also not considered (and if they were, the result would be that the references bind to *temporary* objects created in the conversion, not the object passed as argument).